# Mass matrix for ODE with Julia (Jacobian sparsity)

Tags: matrix, julia

while implementing a stiff matrix ODE in Julia, I notice that the inverse Mass matrix required for the state-space representation (2nd order ODE), leads to a very dense Jacobian matrix:
[image]
for `dx.=[-invM*C -invM*K; eye(Float64, 406, 406) zeros(Float64, 406, 406)]*x`

If instead we remove the inv(Ms) expression, the "Jacobian" of the right-hand side of the ODE is very  sparse, which is no suprise:
[image]
for `"Mass"*dx.=[-C -K; eye(Float64, 406, 406) zeros(Float64, 406, 406)]*x`

Is it possible to improve performance by providing the mass on the left-hand side of the equation, in the form:

```
[Ms zeros(Float64, 406, 406); zeros(Float64, 406,406) eye(Float, 406,406)]
```

I guess this option is available in DifferentialEquations.jl ?

Thank you

Comment: Mass matrices are described in the stiff ODE tutorial under the title [Handling Mass Matrices](https://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/tutorials/advanced_ode_example/#Handling-Mass-Matrices-1). Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Mass matrices are described in the stiff ODE tutorial under the title [Handling Mass Matrices](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/advanced_ode_example/#Handling-Mass-Matrices-1). You define the mass matrix by adding it to the `ODEFunction` as a keyword argument. For example:

```
using DifferentialEquations
function rober(du,u,p,t)
  y₁,y₂,y₃ = u
  k₁,k₂,k₃ = p
  du[1] = -k₁*y₁+k₃*y₂*y₃
  du[2] =  k₁*y₁-k₂*y₂^2-k₃*y₂*y₃
  du[3] =  y₁ + y₂ + y₃ - 1
  nothing
end
M = [1. 0  0
     0  1. 0
     0  0  0]
f = ODEFunction(rober,mass_matrix=M)
prob_mm = ODEProblem(f,[1.0,0.0,0.0],(0.0,1e5),(0.04,3e7,1e4))
sol = solve(prob_mm,Rodas5(),reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8)

plot(sol, xscale=:log10, tspan=(1e-6, 1e5), layout=(3,1))
```

is the mass matrix DAE form of the ROBER equation.

[image]